# Get count of timestamp entries from array newer than some specified timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have an array in Postgres that contains timestamps.  I'd like to count the number of entries in the array newer than a timestamp specified in a query.  As a bonus, I'd like to delete entries in the array older than another specified timestamp.  Can this be done just using SQL in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question,

You can use [`UNNEST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) function to expand an array into rows and then apply `WHERE` clause to filter the array elements.

```sql
SELECT 
  id, 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  (
    select 
      id, 
      UNNEST(mytsarr) AS ts 
    FROM 
      mytable
  ) t 
WHERE 
  ts > '1900-01-01' 
GROUP BY 
  id;
```

Replace `id` column with any unique column in your table.

For the bonus question, the below query will update the array column removing timestamps older than '1900-01-01'.

```sql
UPDATE 
  mytable 
SET
  myarrcol = (
    SELECT 
      array_agg(t) 
    FROM 
      unnest(myarrcol) AS t 
    where 
      t > '1900-01-01'
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a scalar sub-query:

```
select ... other columns ...,
       (select count(*)
        from unnest(the_array_column) as x(ts)
        where x.ts >= timestamp '2022-11-09 08:00:00') as element_count
from the_table;
```